libgdx ShapeRenderer on xz plain
I have set of point on xz-plane and need to draw polygon, probably using ShapeRenderer. But it is intended for xy-plane, and, using my set of points, render polygon in perpendicular to expected position. So my question is, how should I transform ShapeRenderer to project it on xz-plane?
